# bash_profile environment variable question : ruby version will be initialized

Tags: ruby, bash, rbenv

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzRYW.png

```
# Setting for rbenv path
export RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

Above image is bash_profile.

```
Last login: Fri Aug 20 00:19:56 on ttys000
gimchan-yeong@gimchan-yeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
gimchan-yeong@gimchan-yeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % which ruby          
/usr/bin/ruby
gimchan-yeong@gimchan-yeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % source .bash_profile
gimchan-yeong@gimchan-yeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % ruby -v             
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-darwin20]
gimchan-yeong@gimchan-yeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % which ruby          
/Users/gimchan-yeong/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I want the ruby version to be 2.6.6 every time I turn on the terminal.But every time I open a new terminal, it's always 2.6.3.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9zTX.png
I have to do source .bash_profile every time to get 2.6.6.

Do I have to do source .bash_profile every time?

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that the Mac basic shell had changed from bash to zsh. It was solved by simply changing from `source .bash_profile` to `source .zshrc`.